# Make a two column div layout with out position

Tags: html, css

I've the below HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="col1">
                <div class="para">
                    Sinds 2007 is For the Road een gerespecteerd muziekbedrijf met het accent op boekingen, advies en management. Een uitgebreid netwerk van podia, pers en partners in de muziekindustrie vormen de basis waarmee bands en singer-songwriters bij For the Road zich kunnen ontwikkelen tot een succesvolle act. Met de ervaring opgedaan met bands als T-99, Sinas, Cuban Heels, Rob van de Wouw, Carlo de Wijs, New Cool Collective, Zuco103, C-mon & Kypski en vele anderen, helpt For the Road  bands met alle facetten in de aanloop naar succes. Denk hierbij aan boekingen, strategisch management, creative management, pr, advies en het maken van verbindingen met relevante partners. De kracht van For the Road is het helpen van ambitieuze talentvolle bands en singer-songwriters in de opbouwfase naar (groter) succes.
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                Sinds 2007 is For the Road een gerespecteerd muziekbedrijf met het accent op boekingen, advies en management. Een uitgebreid netwerk van podia, pers en partners in de muziekindustrie vormen de basis waarmee bands en singer-songwriters bij For the Road zich kunnen ontwikkelen tot een succesvolle act. Met de ervaring opgedaan met bands als T-99, Sinas, Cuban Heels, Rob van de Wouw, Carlo de Wijs, New Cool Collective, Zuco103, C-mon & Kypski en vele anderen, helpt For the Road  bands met alle facetten in de aanloop naar succes. Denk hierbij aan boekingen, strategisch management, creative management, pr, advies en het maken van verbindingen met relevante partners. De kracht van For the Road is het helpen van ambitieuze talentvolle bands en singer-songwriters in de opbouwfase naar (groter) succes.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the below CSS.

```
.container2 {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    right: 50%;
}

.col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
    left: 52%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
    left: 56%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 5em;
}
```

Here i'm trying to make a 2 column div layout. Here when i run this, in a full screen mode. This works fine. Below is the output.

http://liveweave.com/gqio3u

But when i view it in a small screen the content appears to be like one `div` below another.

Here I know that using `position: relative` would solve the problem. But our app where i need to upload the content onto, doesn't accept `position`, it will throw an error.

Please let me know how can i fix this. I need 2 column layout even when i resize.

Thanks

Comment: your link is not working, fix it please.

Comment: Use bootstrap to make it responsive page

Comment: Hi @KhrisAzuaje, the link is working but taking little time to load.

Comment: @WisdmLabs, I need to use plain HTML and CSS

Comment: You can use media queries for mobile devices and use 50% width in the mobile device media query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/770e1efu/1/)

```
.col1 {
   float: left;
   width: 45%;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-right:2%;
 }

.col2 {
   float: left;
   width: 45%;
   overflow: hidden;  padding-left:2%;
 }
```

Please have a look, this will do the trick for you.

Comment: @user3872094 for the best results please use [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/), it will be more helpful for you.